# Yesod Web Framework in the marketplace

Tags: yesod

Is the Yesod Web Framework for Haskell being used at any established sites on the Internet, other than yesodweb.net? Are any companies using it?

I am considering starting a site and am looking at frameworks.

Comment: I don't know but Yesod is awesome, I'm starting with it and I'm really impressed. Anyway, (I think) the app kind is a strong factor (what app kind it'll to be?).

Comment: As dedicated and ambitious a developer as Michael Snoyman is, I hesitate to invest a large amount of effort developing a website using Yesod if no other sites are using it. If Michael decides to move on to other pursuits, there will be little to keep the framework alive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a freely contributed [list at the wiki](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Powered-by-Yesod).

But searching for "Powered by Yesod" with Google gives 63.200 pages at the moment.

Using Multi-engine sites should filter a lot. [IxQuick](https://www.ixquick.com/do/search) for example. [ITools](http://itools.com/search/web-search#q=%22powered+by+yesod%22&submit=Search&tool=bing-web-search) permit to switch search engines.

The [Google-groups Yesod forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!members/yesodweb) has 383 interested members by now.